# User Defined Operator VBA

Tags: vba, operators

Is it possible to define a custom operaotr in VBA? I am not seeing any documentation on it. I know I could write a function but I was wondering about using an operator and whether or not that would have any performance benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't overload/override operators in VBA, they're baked into the parser and compiler/interpreter, and there's no tampering with them.

[VBA Language Specs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156871.aspx)

Comment: Booooo need custom operators :(

Comment: i think this just means i get to step into a new language where i get syntax suggary thing

Comment: the reason I asked about this in the first place is i want a non IIF ternary statement in vba LOL

Comment: If I could make a custom operator in VBA, I'd add VB.NET's `AndAlso` and `OrElse` short-circuiting logical operators, analoguous to C#'s `&&` and `||` operators, respectively. That's one set of operators that's cruelly missing from VBA IMO.

Comment: yeah that would be really cool. hell if they'd just up the vba game in general that would be sweet. I mean I started branching out b/c threading is a thing